# The equivalent of ReadLn in pascal in javascript

Tags: javascript

So basically i wanted to know the equivalent of ReadLn in pascal in javascript like how to get data from the user precisely strings.

Comment: in the browser or node?

Answer (score 0):

The command that come close to readln is prompt().

```js
prompt()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it with node : https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html